# MongoDB: Create Fields only if not exist

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I want to create a update Script on this data:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5b87e83d881ba01dfc3b0367"),
"Views" : [
    {
        "ReportUniqueKey" : "AAA",
        "GroupMode" : NumberInt("0"),
        "DisplayName" : "Default",
        "Columns" : [],
        "UnusedOptionalFilterParameter" : null,
        "IsDefault" : true,
        "LastModified" : ISODate("0001-01-01T01:00:00.000+01:00"),
        "LastModifiedUserId" : NumberInt("0"),
        "Guid": "6988FBD83E5A4C889E8E96646033D836"
    },
    {
        "ReportUniqueKey" : "9E91595D92DE4E01B72895B1B88C474D",
        "GroupMode" : NumberInt("0"),
        "DisplayName" : "Pro Tour",
        "Columns" : [],
        "UnusedOptionalFilterParameter" : null,
        "IsDefault" : false,
        "LastModified" : ISODate("2018-08-03T13:13:20.330+02:00"),
        "LastModifiedUserId" : NumberInt("1")
    }
]}
```

This is only one Document there are more of them. Now i want to Update all Views Objects where the Field "Guid" is not existing or null/Empty string. If the Guid is set to a Value don't update the Field.

The Guid is generated by this function:

```
function S4() {
return (((1+Math.random())*0x10000)|0).toString(16).substring(1);}
function generateGuid(){
return  (S4() + S4() + S4() + S4() + S4() + S4() + S4() + S4()).toUpperCase();}
```

How can i achieve this update for all documents? I have found this on the MongoDB site but i don't know how i can get into the array.

```
db.TestGuid.aggregate([{$project:{Guid:{$ifNull: [ "$Guid", "Test"]}}}])
```

How can i get this script to work on an array of Objects?

Comment: Do you want to update in database or aggregate the result only?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I want to update in database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have write an c# script to perform this action to generate a better Guid. I added the Field with this Command:

```
var pipeline = new[] { new BsonDocument() { { "$addFields", new BsonDocument() { { "Views.Guid", "" } } } } };
```

Then i load all documents per MongoDriver and set a new Guid for each Document.

I also sorting the elements in the Columns Field so a c# script is better for me.